# UITableViewCell detailTextLabel not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Using a `UITableView` and its `UITableViewCell`(s) in Swift. I have some problem showing the `detailTextLabel` field of a `UITableViewCell`.

I already found these two helpful posts, but could not get a fully working solution:
[swift detailTextLabel not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216349/swift-detailtextlabel-not-showing-up)
[How to Set UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle and dequeueReusableCell in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062285/how-to-set-uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-and-dequeuereusablecell-in-swift)

Here is the code I am using, relevant to my question:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

………….
    theTableView = UITableView(frame: tmpFrame)
………….
    theTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    theTableView.dataSource = self
    theTableView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(theTableView)
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "THE-TEXT-LABEL"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "KIJILO" // This does not show up.
    return cell
}
```

When I try to make use of the `detailTextLabel` field of `UITableViewCell`, it does not show up. Searching on the net, I understand that I have to use the proper style(`UITableViewCellStyle`) for the cell, but I do not see how to integrate that change into my code. The examples I've seen are based on subclassing `UITableViewCell` and I suppose I do not need to subclass `UITableViewCell` only to make use of the `detailTextLabel` field. Please tell me if I am wrong.

I have also tried a few things from the posts mentioned above, but nothing works as I want.

Comment: You need the code in the 2nd link you posted but only after you remove the use of the `theTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")` line.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You've registered the UITableViewCell

```
theTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,
 forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

This means that when you call

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", 
forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

one will be automatically created for you using the UITableViewCellStyleDefault style.

Because you want a custom style you need to do a few things:

Remove

```
theTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, 
forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

Replace

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", 
forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

with the following

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier")
if cell == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
}
```

What is happening here is `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will return nil if it can't dequeue a cell. You can then generate your own cell providing with the specified style.

Comment: I wish I cud have given u +10..! Thank you..!

Comment: `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always returns nil in better case, in worse case `detailTextLabel` is nil

Comment: got solved. register tableview cell take cell = UITableViewCell() never call

Comment: Upvoted. There is nothing wrong with this approach and while it's not a hack, it just _looks_ like a hack,

Comment: If you have a custom cell then all you have to do is:               
`var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customReuseIdentifier")
if cell == nil {
    cell = CustomCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: "customReuseIdentifier")
}`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `Storyboard`:

1. select a cell
2. go to attributes inspector
3. click style
4. choose `Subtitle`

Answer (score 2):

I found that it's not enough to check if the `cell` is `nil.` I added this additional check:

```swift
var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
if cell == nil || cell?.detailTextLabel == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I think you think it does

Answer (score 0):

Great answer, thank you!  The only thing I'd add is that if you want a different style of detail view (I was looking for .subtitle) you'll want to do the following:

cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")

where: CellStyle : Int

```
    case `default` = 0

    case value1 = 1

    case value2 = 2

    case subtitle = 3
```